# Java Runtime is not formatting correctly python args

Tags: java, python, spring-boot

```
private static void sendEmailGeneric(String titleMessage, String textMessage, String email, String subject, List<HashMap<String, String>> attachmentPaths) {
        /*F
         * Attachment tiene la siguiente estructura:
         * List -> HashMap({ file_path: string, file_title: string })
         * */
        ArrayList<String> attachmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (HashMap<String, String> attachmentPath : attachmentPaths) {
            attachmentList.add(attachmentPath.get("file_title").concat(":").concat(attachmentPath.get("file_path")));
        }
        LOGGER.info("Adjuntando ".concat(attachmentList.toString()));
        String mailerPath = new File("/opt/sintesis/api/mailer/mailer.py").getAbsolutePath();
        String[] builder = {"python3",
                mailerPath,
                "\"".concat(email).concat("\""),
                "\"".concat(subject).concat("\""),
                "\"".concat(titleMessage).concat("\""),
                "\"".concat(textMessage).concat("\""),
                "\"".concat(attachmentList.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "")).concat("\"")};
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(builder);
            LOGGER.info("Ejecutando mailer ".concat(builder.toString()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            LOGGER.error("Ha sucedido un error al enviar el correo a ".concat(email).concat(", con asunto: ").concat(subject));
        }
    }
```

I have this code that calls a python script, the problem is the params are not correctly displayed

```
python3 mailer.py mymail@mail.com "This is a test" "Subuject" "Message" "index:index.html,dna.pdf"
```

Where the " character is not formatted in java and is deleting. So what i'm doing wrong because I try many things and nothing works.

When the message is sended is the title message in mail show me like that **"This**
The title is **is** and the message is **a**

So i'm guessing the problem is in the java parser or some like that.

Comment: Are you sure you nee the quotes? There is no shell involved, no word splitting happens.

Comment: I try without the quotes, the script didn't work. The thing here is the messages will be very long "long long long long words" " another long word" "long path of files" so I need the quotes to separate the args. I try with process builder and same error with arguments without "